# trying to xss a site

Tags: xss

```
http://XXX/?subscribe_message=%3Cscript%3Ealert(/zzz/);%3C/script%3E
```

Why doesn't that popup with a /zzz/ alert? When I do `javascript:alert(/zzz/);` in the address bar it does so why not when I do it via the URL? A look at the source code makes me think it /should/ work...

Comment: Do you have formal written approval to test their website?

Comment: do you think he have a written approval if he doesn't know why it doesn't work?

Comment: @lucian maybe he's legitemately testing the site and has a question about it? Is it because you have an approval that suddenly all vulnerabilities drop auto-magically into your lap and get fused into the most epic pentest report ever? Yea I didn't think so.

Comment: Maybe I'm way too sceptic about people...

Comment: It does work, at least for me on Firefox.

Comment: HE might have approval, but WE don't.

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers like Chrome have anti-XSS features which block obvious attacks. If you open the JavaScript console of your browser, you should see the warnings.

Either turn off the protection temporarily or use a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to test a particular website to check for xss vulnerabilities, I use this Firefox plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/xss-me/

It gives you a nice first impression of possible vulnerabilities that exist. It is recommended to study up on JS and XSS in particular. Do not go for a scriptkiddie approach :)